# Selenium Java - Impossible closing a MacOs mail dialog box

Tags: java, macos, email, selenium-webdriver

I have the next drama:

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Java in MacOS.
I need to close a Mail inbox dialog, but it's impossible.

I have tried with iterators, alerts, robot class, but I can't.

[image]

It is impossible to close that window "Inbox (Read Only) 
I have tried many things to make click in the Quit button, but I 
can't.

Comment: Probably because it's a system window and the browser does not have control over it.

Comment: It looks like this is in a completely separate application (Inbox); what you may need to do is prevent your browser from transferring `mailto:` links to it.

Comment: The test case says that it must click in a link (Mail) and display this box. The thing is how to close it.

Comment: did you get the window handle and switch to the pop up window (if it is a popup window and not an alert to dismiss)

Comment: Yes, I already did it.